# Eclipse Scroll Pane Cutting Parts of its Content Away

Tags: linux, eclipse, user-interface, ubuntu

Like I say in the title, Eclipse Neon's scroll panes cut away parts of their content. Here's a screenshot showing what I mean:
[image]

Notice they light-gray rectangles at the bottom, side, and top of the scroll pane containing the Java code. Same thing happens with any other scrollable GUI object in Eclipse, and it's becoming rather annoying.

This is happening in the latest version of Eclipse Neon running on Ubuntu 16.04 with the latest OpenJDK.

Any help with resolving this issue is appreciated.

Comment: Does commenting my own post bump it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I was using a GTK+ theme than did not work well with Eclipse, and was causing said issue (the theme in question was a Windows-10-lookalike theme).